# How to optimize using Genetic Algorithm to get integer values?

Tags: genetic-algorithm

Say I have 3 parameters x1, x2 and x3, where x1, x2 and x3 can all take *integer* values between 0 to 9. I use GA to minimize an objective function f(x1,x2,x3), but the values of x1, x2 and x3 obtained should be integers. Any R-based implementation of GA with such a function to obtain integer values instead of the usual real values would be helpful.

Comment: Use 'as. integer' .